# Remove TChart from form programmatically

Tags: delphi, teechart

I'm looking for the correct way in order to remove a TChart and deallocate all the memory.
I am using Delphi2007 with the standard TeeChart 7

I create the TChart programmatically:

```
var parentform: TForm;
begin
newchart:= TChart.Create(parentform);
newchart.Parent:= parentform;
...
```

Then, I want to remove only the chart from the form (not closing the form itself), but I get only that the chart becomes blank and stays on the form:

```
newChart.FreeAllSeries;
FreeAndNil(newChart);
```

if I use

```
NewChart.Parent := nil,
```

I don't see the chart anymore, but I think the TChart object still exists (until the parentform is destroyed). Is there a specific method for doing this?
Thank you

Comment: The chart doesn't exist after the `FreeAndNil` call.

Comment: Why did you call TChart.Create twice and leak the first one? Is this your real code? Freeing the chart should be enough.

Comment: Actually this is a simplified part of the code, it was an error of copy and paste. Thank you very much for the quick response, I tryed again with my original code and it works. I suppose I was testing an old version without the FreeAndNil call... And I suppose I'll try to FreeandNil this question on stackoverflow as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward way to get rid of a `TChart` control, or just about any control, for that matter, is to call `Free` on it:

```
newChart.Free;
```

You can call `FreeAndNil` instead if you wish. That has the same effect of calling `Free`, but also sets the variable's value to `nil`. That's useful if you later test the variable's value to detect whether you still have access to the control. If you never reference the variable again, then `FreeAndNil` doesn't get you much.

The control will automatically free the other things it owns, such as the series you manually freed with `FreeAllSeries`. You don't need to free them yourself.

Merely clearing the control's `Parent` property does not free the control. You can prove that by re-assigning the `Parent` property and watching as the control re-appears on the screen. That wouldn't happen if the control had ceased to exist.

If the control remains visible on the screen after you free it, then you have other problems. Maybe the parent control hasn't repainted itself properly. You might try calling `Refresh` on the parent control. You might also have multiple controls visible. After all, the question's code creates *two* chart controls, so maybe one of them is still visible, and you've mistaken it for the control you destroyed.

Comment: Is it not preferred to use `Release` instead of `Free` for components?

Comment: @Arnaud: No. `Release` is designed for another purpose entirely. It's for releasing a form and all of it's components from inside an event handler of that form. See [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Release) for more info.

Comment: If you were freeing the chart component from within one of the chart's own methods, then yes, @Arnaud, a `Release`-like technique would be a good idea. However, `TComponent` has no such method. And besides, there's no indication in the question that such complication is necessary. People are free to ask follow-up questions if the usual way doesn't work for them.

Comment: I indeed made a confusion with TForm. Thanks for the precision!